# How to automatically mount network share when iPhone backup screen is opened in Finder?

Tags: macos, iphone, finder, applescript, automator

I would like to trigger a script that mounts a drive when I open the iPhone's device page in Finder (like shown [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203060)).

[image]

Currently, I have the iPhone backups in an APFS volume, which is inside a SparseBundle, which is on a SMB share on my NAS.
Before running an iPhone backup, I mount the drive by manually running a shell script.

Since I work on a MacBook the LAN with my NAS is not always available, hence the detour with mounting manually. But triggering the mount process automatically when entering the page in finder seems a good idea.

- Is there any event fired to attach such a script to?
- Or maybe there is any other sensible method to mount the drive automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a *script* can be triggered when the **iPhone** is connected...

When the **iPhone** is connected to the **Mac**, the following *file* gets modified:

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist
```

Using a **Launch Agent** with a `WatchPaths` *key* it can be determined if the **iPhone** is connected to the **Mac** when the **NetworkInterfaces.plist** *file* is modified.

For testing purposes, I created the *launch agent* as:

```bash
$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.iphone.connected.plist
```

Contents of the **com.me.iphone.connected.plist** *file*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.iphone.connected</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/iPhone</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In the **XML PLIST** *file*, **/usr/local/bin/iPhone** is a *shell script* that gets executed when there is a change to the   **NetworkInterfaces.plist** *file* and the contents of the *shell script* is:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

iPhone="$(/usr/bin/defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist | /usr/bin/grep -m 1 -o 'iPhone')"

if [[ -n "$iPhone" ]]; then
    if [[ -d "/Volumes/Data" ]]; then
        if [[ ! -d "/Volumes/iPhone Backup" ]]; then
            open "/Volumes/Data/iPhone_Backup.sparsebundle"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

When the example *shell script* is executed it assumes I'm already connected to the **Network Share**, in this example it's "**Data**", but it first sets the *value* of the `iPhone` *variable* by using the `defaults` *command* to *read* the `.plist` *file* and *pipes* its *output* to `grep` to return the first occurrence of "**iPhone**" if found. If the **iPhone** is connected, then `iPhone="iPhone"` and the *test* in the first `if` *statement* succeeds.

The next *test* succeeds if I am connected to **Data**, and the subsequent *test* succeeds if I'm not already connected to my **iPhone Backup** *sparsebundle*. It's coded in this manner so as not to try opening the *sparsebundle* if it's already mounted if the **NetworkInterfaces.plist** *file* is modified again while the *sparsebundle* is already mounted. In other words, the *sparsebundle* is only opened if it's not already mounted.

If you also want the mounting of the **SMB** *share* to occur in the, e.g. `iPhone`, *shell script*, you can add the following example *command* directly after the opening of the first `if` *statement*. In other words, literally between the first two `if` *statements*:

```bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'mount volume "smb://user:@server/share"'
```

This uses **AppleScript** *code* to mount the *target share* and assumes the credentials are already stored in your **Keychain**. It also is not problematic if the **SMB** *share* is already mounted, then the *command* just fails silently.

---

**Notes:**

Had you included the *script* or *code* you are already using, I would have created a working example that would have incorporated it, however what I've submitted is an example that works for me tested under **macOS Catalina**.

I recommend you read the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`. You can read the *manual page* for `command` in **Terminal** by typing `command` and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

After creating the `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.iphone.connected.plist` *file* I loaded it using the `launchctl` *command*, e.g.:

```bash
cd "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/"
launchctl load com.me.iphone.connected.plist
```

Once loaded, it will automatically load when you login to your account, so you shouldn't need to do it manually again under normal circumstances. To unload it, use the `unload` *subcommand* with the `launchctl` *command*.

After unloading it, you can use the `disable` *subcommand* so it doesn't load again or you can delete the .`plist` *file*, if/when you want to undo changes you've made to your *system*.